# How can I create a tkinter python object to be 50% opacity?

Tags: python, tkinter, colors, transparency

I tried the parameter "opacity=.5" and "alpha=.5"

Another problem is that fill="ff00ff00" also doesn't work.

I also used the tkinter canvas.

I also saw.some other similar questions, but they don't answer my specific question.

Nothing really seems to work, so could you help me please?

Comment: Kindly explain where you want to fill color with opacity preferably with part of the code. It looks like you want to create a shape filled with some color.

Comment: No one knows what you have done without a [mre].

Comment: Individual components cannot be given opacity, but you can give it to the entire window, by following the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the object is named "button", try this:

```
button.attributes("-alpha", 0.5)
```

Comment: Individual components cannot be given "opacity"